# How to adapt this query to use window functions

Tags: sql, postgresql, aggregate-functions, window-functions, cumulative-sum

When I started tackling this problem, I thought, "This will be a great query to learn about Window Functions." I wasn't able to end up getting it to work with window functions, but I was able to get what I wanted using a join.

How would you adapt this query to use window functions:

```
SELECT
    day,
    COUNT(i.project) as num_open
FROM generate_series(0, 364) as t(day)
    LEFT JOIN issues i on (day BETWEEN i.closed_days_ago AND i.created_days_ago)
GROUP BY day
ORDER BY day;
```

The query above takes a list of issues that have a range represented by created_days_ago and closed_days ago and for the last 365 days, it'll count the number of issues that were created but not yet closed for that specific day.

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/663f6/2

The `issues` table looks like:

```
CREATE TABLE issues (
  id SERIAL,
  project VARCHAR(255),
  created_days_ago INTEGER,
  closed_days_ago INTEGER);
```

What I was thinking was that the partition for a given day should include all the rows in issues where day is between the created and closed days ago. Something like `SELECT day, COUNT(i.project) OVER (PARTITION day BETWEEN created_days_ago AND closed_days_ago) ...`

I've never used window functions before, so I might be missing something basic, but it seemed like this was just the type of query that makes window functions so awesome.

Comment: I don't think a window will apply usefully for this. You need `generate_series` to create the rowset. Window functions cannot generate wholly new rows, so you can't create rows for those days with zero issues using window functions, or generate a row for those days on which no issue was opened or closed.

Comment: "created_days_ago integer" -- ouch. You actually run a cron to increment this daily instead of storing a timestamp or a date? :-(

Comment: @Denis, they're actually stored as dates in the actual table and comes back is a calculated days_ago value in a view. I just simplified it a bit for this question.

Comment: +1 for presenting a complete case (for an interesting question) including a working fiddle. Only your version of Postgres is missing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The fact that you use `generate_series()` to create a full range of days, including those days with no changes, and thus no rows in table `issues`, does *not* rule out the use of window functions.

In fact, this query runs 50 times **faster** than the query in the Q in my local test:

```
SELECT t.day
      ,  COALESCE(sum(a.created) OVER (ORDER BY t.day DESC), 0)
       - COALESCE(sum(b.closed)  OVER (ORDER BY t.day DESC), 0) AS open_tickets
FROM   generate_series(0, 364) t(day)
LEFT   JOIN (SELECT created_days_ago AS day, count(*) AS created
             FROM   issues GROUP BY 1) a USING (day)
LEFT   JOIN (SELECT closed_days_ago AS day, count(*) AS closed
             FROM   issues GROUP BY 1) b USING (day)
ORDER  BY 1;
```

It is also **correct**, as opposed to the query in the question, which results in 17 open tickets on day 0, although all of them have been closed.
The error is due to `BETWEEN` in your join condition, which includes upper *and* lower border. This way tickets are still counted as "open" on the day they are closed.

Each row in the result reflects the number of open tickets *at the end of the day*.

#### Explain

The query *combines* window functions with aggregate functions.

- Subquery `a` counts the number of created tickets per day. This results in a single row per day, making the rest easier.
  Subquery `b` does the same for closed tickets.
- Use LEFT JOINs to join to the generated list of days in  subquery `t`.
  Be wary of joining to multiple unaggregated tables! That could trigger a `CROSS JOIN` among the joined tables for multiple matches per row, generating incorrect results. Compare:
  [Two SQL LEFT JOINS produce incorrect result](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12464037/two-sql-left-joins-produce-incorrect-result/12464135#12464135)
- Finally use two window functions to compute the running total of created versus closed tickets.
  An alternative would be to use this in the outer `SELECT`

  ```
  sum(COALESCE(a.created, 0)
    - COALESCE(b.closed,  0)) OVER (ORDER BY t.day DESC) AS open_tickets
  ```

  Performs the same in my tests.

[**-> SQLfiddle demo.**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/663f6/6)

Aside: I would never store "days_ago" in a table, but the absolute date / timestamp. Looks like a simplification for the purpose of this question.

Comment: Good point. I was taking the question as "how do I replace this join with use of a window over the original table" - and you can't really do that, but as you've shown a much better question is still possible with use of running totals.

Comment: @CraigRinger: I assume you mean "a much better *query*".

Comment: Er. Yes. A much better *query*. I blame morning.

Comment: Excellent! Just what I was looking for to help me understand window functions. Thanks.

Comment: @StevePrentice: Nice. I added some more advice.